# Dynamically set panel height using height of a gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview, panel

Im trying to set the height of an asp panel on a web form dynamically, in relation to the height of a gridview within that panel.
I thought I could do something like

```
pnlScanItem.Height = gvAllItems.Height + 30;
```

or

```
pnlScanItem.Height = Convert.ToInt32(gvAllItems.Height) + 30;
```

but both give errors, can anyone tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try ?

```
panel.MaximumSize = new Size(YouWidth, YourHeight);
panel.Size = new Size(YouWidth, panel.Height);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: It's not a windows form it's a web form, so I'm not using System.Windows.Forms unfortunately.  I should've said that at the start, will update post.